# Laravel - syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '['

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8 to create an App. When I wanted to display the view, it generated an error as shown below:

[image: new error screen]

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '['

[image: unexpected]

Controller

```
    public function serviceOverview(Request $request)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Subscription Overview';
$serviceoverviews = DB::table("service_package")
   ->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'service_package.service_id')
   ->join('service_type', 'service_type.id', '=', 'services.service_type')
   ->select('service_package.title as service_id', 'service_package.title as package_name', DB::raw("DATE(service_package.created_at) as created_at"), 'service_package.price', 'service_package.days','services.name as service_name','service_type.name as service_type');

$render=[];

    if(isset($request->package_name))
    {
        $serviceoverviews=$serviceoverviews->where('serviceoverviews','like','%'.$request->serviceoverviews.'%');
        $render['package_name']=$request->package_name;
    }    
    if(isset($request->service_id))
    {
        $serviceoverviews=$serviceoverviews->where('service_id',$request->service_id);
        $render['service_id']=$request->service_id;
    }

    $serviceoverviews= $serviceoverviews->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $serviceoverviews= $serviceoverviews->paginate(15);
    $serviceoverviews= $serviceoverviews->appends($render);
    $data['serviceoverviews'] = $serviceoverviews;    

    return view('report.serviceOverview',$data);
}
```

In the Controller, I tried to do some filtering. Also, I did raw query.

View

```
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            @if(Session::has('flash_message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
        </div>
        @endif 
        @if(count($detailsubscriptions))            
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condesed" id="commenter_info_table">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Service</td>
            <td>Package</td>
            <td>Service Type</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Days</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach($serviceoverviews as $key => serviceoverview)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>{{ serviceoverview->service_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->package_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->service_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ serviceoverview->created_at }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->price }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->days }}</td>                
            </tr>

        @endforeach
            <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                {{ $serviceoverview->links() }}
            </td>
            </tr>         
    </tbody>  

    </table>   
            @else
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h2>No Service Overview to show</h2>
        </div>
        @endif        
    </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to check the code, but found nothing. How do I resolve this issue

Comment: You are missing `$` sign

Comment: Since this was just a typographical error, I have voted to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code updated with changes. Please refer to this

**Controller.php**

```
public function serviceOverview(Request $request)
{
    $builder = DB::table("service_package")
                    ->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'service_package.service_id')
                    ->join('service_type', 'service_type.id', '=', 'services.service_type')
                    ->select('service_package.title as service_id', 'service_package.title as package_name', DB::raw("DATE(service_package.created_at) as created_at"), 'service_package.price', 'service_package.days','services.name as service_name','service_type.name as service_type');

    if($request->filled('package_name'))) {

        $builder = $builder->where('serviceoverviews','like','%'.$request->serviceoverviews.'%');
    }    

    if(isset($request->service_id))
    {
        $builder=$builder->where('service_id',$request->service_id);
    }

    $serviceoverviews = $builder->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(15);

    $data = [
        'title' => 'Subscription Overview',
        'serviceoverviews' => $serviceoverviews
    ];

    return view('report.serviceOverview', $data);
}
```

Now change your view code like this.

**view.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condesed" id="commenter_info_table">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Service</td>
            <td>Package</td>
            <td>Service Type</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Days</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach($serviceoverviews as $key => $serviceoverview)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->service_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->package_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->service_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ serviceoverview->created_at }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->price }}</td>
                <td>{{ $serviceoverview->days }}</td>                
            </tr>

        @endforeach
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                {{ $serviceoverview->appends(\Request::all())->links() }}
            </td>
        </tr>         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nicely spotted!

Comment: After doing all those corrections, I now have another error:    htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: @user11352561 change this `<td>{{ serviceoverview->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>`.

Comment: The error is still there. I've updated the error screen in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194878/discussion-between-lakhwinder-singh-and-user11352561).

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a `$` from the `$serviceoverview` variable in your blade `@foreach`. Change:

```
@foreach($serviceoverviews as $key => serviceoverview)
```

To

```
@foreach($serviceoverviews as $key => $serviceoverview)
```

Comment: After doing all those corrections, I now have another error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Answer (score 0):

You are using `serviceoverview` in place of `$serviceoverview` in view file. That would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have made some typo and one logical error.

Change

1. `@foreach($serviceoverviews as $key => serviceoverview)` to `@foreach($serviceoverviews as $key => $serviceoverview)`
2. `<td>{{ serviceoverview->service_name }}</td>` to `<td>{{ $serviceoverview->service_name }}</td>`
3. You have put `{{ $serviceoverview->links() }}` out side of the `foreach` loop